# Checkboxes with Perl CGI

Tags: html, perl, checkbox, cgi

Sorry if my question is too simple, I am just starting out with CGI...
So I have a bunch of checkboxes with the same name. Sample HTML:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/checkbox.cgi" method="POST">
<input name="Loc_opt" value="Loc_1" type="checkbox">Option 1<br>
<input name="Loc_opt" value="Loc_2" type="checkbox">Option 2<br>
<input name="Loc_opt" value="Loc_3" type="checkbox">Option 3<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I need to find out which of them are checked using Perl CGI. I have the following in checkbox.cgi:

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
local ($buffer, @pairs, $pair, $name, $value, %FORM);
    # Read in text
    $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
    if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST")
    {
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    }else {
    $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
    }
    # Split information into name/value pairs
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs)
    {
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }
```

What should I do to now print, say, the values of the selected checkboxes?

Comment: Where did you get that code from? Whatever book or web site you found it on, please stop reading it now. It's about fifteen years out of date and contains at least two potential problems.

Comment: @Dave I found this code [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_cgi.htm). Could you please let me know what are the problems and what should be the correct code? I would appreciate it if you put your reply as a separate answer.

Comment: Yeah. Any CGI tutorial that doesn't use CGI.pm should really be ignored. That module has been included with Perl for 15 years and nakes writing CGO programs far easier. The two problems I noted are 1/ It assumes that parameters are separated by '&' (';' is also allowed) and 2/ It breaks if a single parameter name has multiple associated values. There may well be more problems. Just use the `param` function from CGI.pm.

Comment: @DaveCross thanks for the suggestion! I am rewriting my code using CGI.pm now, it seems to be much neater.

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the param() result into an array if you have multiple form elements with the same name.From [CGI101](http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch5/text.html):

```
my @colors = param('color');
foreach my $color (@colors) {
    print "You picked $color.<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my @opt = $cgi->param('Loc_opt');
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read the Perl documentation for the [CGI module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html).  There are easy, built-in ways to handle all this.